# Confusion in JavaScript RegExp ? Quantifier

Tags: javascript, regex

May I know the reason of getting the output of the following code as: 1,10,10? Why not it is as: 10, 10?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var str="1, 100 or 1000?";
var patt1=/10?/g; 
document.write(str.match(patt1));
</script>
```

Comment: @Dusk: what did you want or expected the output to be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the `?` is a special character in regex, it's an operator makes the single item before it optional. Thus, `/10?/` matches a 1 optionally followed by a 0. Hence why it can match just `1`, or the `10` in 100, or the `10` in 1000.

Answer (score 1):

this is a [handy cheat sheet for reg expressions](http://opencompany.org/download/regex-cheatsheet.pdf).

the bit that you need is in the middle:

- 0 or more matches = *
- 0 or 1 matches = ?
- 1 or more matches = +

you can see the different effects these have, using your code, [here](http://jsbin.com/unili4/edit)

Answer (score 1):

? is a meta-character meaning zero-or-more matches.

To match '?', escape.

```
var pat = /10\?/g;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may be confusing the precedence

```
/10?/
```

This applies `?` only to `0`. If you want `10` to be modified with `?`, then you'd have to group it:

```
/(10)?/
```

Or, if you don't need to capture:

```
/(?:10)?/
```

Similarly,

```
/ab+/
```

Matches `abbbbbb`. If you want to match `ababab`, then you'd have to write:

```
/(?:ab)+/
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed:

```
/10+\?/g
```